# При попытке подключения по протоколу WS к серверу написанному на си, при попытке чтения recv бесконечно читает 0 байт

Tags: c, http, websocket, unix

Проблема такая. Я пытаюсь реализовать свой веб сервер, поддерживающий протоклы HTTP и WS. Если до того, как произошло подключение по протоколу Ws сервер отдавал данные по протоколу HTTP, при условии, что номер файлового дескриптора подключения по WS совпадает с номером дескриптора, который система давала HTTP подключению до этого, то recv бесконечно читает 0 байт. При этом подключение закрывается с помощью close. Как это исправить?